# How to handle Heroku idle?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have an issue where heroku apps goes idle every 2mins, which makes the user wait a few minutes to get a payment request. Is there a way to solve this issue? Also what are some good alternatives to heroku? I'm also seeing low scores on Google Page Insights and I'm guessing that's because heroku is idle most of the time. My app is built in nodejs and react

Answer (score 0):

There are many different deployment solutions available; It really depends what kind of functionality is important to you as a developer. There are other Heroku-esque solutions, such as [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) who over CD as well as Git integration. Any cloud provider will also be able to do a good job of hosting your application at a low cost. I personally, use [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/), but [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/), and [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/) will do an equally good job.

You can deploy your Node/React app to an [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance, as long as you're reasonably proficient at Linux system configuration, and it will be extremely low cost and very fast.